# ¿Cómo hacer un conteo SQL con las sentencia CASE when case?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una duda sobre como hacer una consulta.

Tengo el Case when, que me lo ejecuta en total haciendo una división de resultados. Y estoy tratando de crear un SP donde, al poner Coche, Hogar o Moto me devuelva el acumulado de ventas.

Actualmente consigo que me devuelva todos pero al poner un nombre de fichero simplemente me cambia el nombre del archivo, no me saca únicamente el resultado del archivo.

```
@Fichero nvarchar(150)
AS

Select fichero, count (@fichero)as division
from [dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros]
GROUP BY fichero



Select t.Fichero ,
    CASE
        when Left(@Fichero, 10) = '%COCHE%' then (Select count (fichero) from [dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros] where fichero = 'COCHES_DIC_21_A' --'COCHES')
        when Left(@Fichero, 9) = '%HOGAR%' then (Select count (fichero) from [dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros] where fichero = 'HOGAR_DIC_21_A' --'HOGAR')
        when Left(@Fichero, 9) = '%MOTOS%' then (Select count (fichero) from [dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros] where fichero = 'MOTOS_DIC_21_A' --'MOTOS')
    END AS division , Right(@Fichero, 8) as division
    from [Negocio].[dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros] t
    GROUP BY Fichero
    HAVING COUNT(*)>0
```

De resultado quiero algo similiar a esto:

[image: Ej. Resultado]

Y con un SP, al poner coches, motos y hogar me diga directamente el resultado de uno de ellos.

Algunos datos de ej son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias mostrar algunos datos de origen? la query, no tiene mucho sentido como esta escrita... Estas haciendo lo mismo varias veces y se puede simplificar muchisimo...

Comment: Perdona, los acabo de añadir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno no entiendo porque escribiste la query de esa forma, salvo que haya cosas que no nos estes mostrando.

Esta query, deberia darte el mismo resultado:

```
Select t.Fichero ,
    count(fichero) AS division,
    Right(fichero, 8) as division_2
from [Negocio].[dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros] t
GROUP BY Fichero
HAVING COUNT(*)>0
```

Ahora, si vos quisieras obtener uno solo de los ficheros, bastaria con agregar una clausula where a tu consulta:

```
Select t.Fichero ,
    count(fichero) AS division,
    Right(fichero, 8) as division_2
from [Negocio].[dbo].[BBDD_Ficheros] t
where fichero = "" //aca
GROUP BY Fichero
HAVING COUNT(*)>0
```

Comment: estoy tratando de crear un SP, por eso lo hago de esta forma, de tal forma que al abrir el SP y poner coche, moto u hogar me de como resultado el conteo

Comment: Pero para eso te basta con la segunda query....